# getJSON: how to try to get some url until success in every 0.5 second?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, loops

So currently I use simple try once:

```
$.getJSON("server.json", function(data) {
        servicesList.render(data);
});
```

I wonder how to try until success each 0.5 seconds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function getFromServer(){
  $.getJSON("server.json", function(data) {
          // Verify your data, if it's not you want run error function 
          if(!data){ onerror(); return; }
          servicesList.render(data);
  }).error(function() { onerror(); });
}

// if error ,run it again.
function onerror(){
    setTimeout(function(){getFromServer();},500);
}
```

you can find the $.getJSON API help with this link:
   http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Answer (score 2):

Try this logic:

```
function update_it() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'server.json',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
      servicesList.render(data);
    },
    error: function() {
      setTimeout('update_it', 500);
    }
  });
}
```

If fail, it waits 500 ms then recalls the function.